# Retry task on a Windows node if unreachable

Tags: ansible, winrm

Is there a way to retry a task if the Windows node is **temporarily** unreachable?

For example, I tried

```yaml
- name: Hello
  ansible.windows.win_powershell:
    script: | 
      Write-Host "hello"
  register: _status
  until: _status is not unreachable
  retries: 3
  delay: 200
```

But, after 30 seconds, I got

```
fatal: [mylocalwin]: UNREACHABLE! => changed=false 
  msg: 'certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host=''xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'', port=5986): Max retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f4160b63eb0>, ''Connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx timed out. (connect timeout=30)''))'
  unreachable: true
```

I would like to retry three times before failing.

Comment: It works sometimes? Or never worked? I dont mean the retries, i mean the task itself. Did you try to run it alone without delays or retries?

Comment: It always works, but sometimes it fails. I would like to handle these occasional fails, for example there is a short network outage (few seconds) when the playbook runs

Comment: What version of powershell are you running, on the remote machine?

Comment: 5.1.17763.3770
But it happens occasionally for a generic "win" tasks

Comment: I cant give you a clear answer, because i think the issue is that winrm timesout and he cuts the connection to the host. That makes sense for me but i dont know the behaviour of it. As a side thing maybe you can try to use rescue blocks, instead of retries. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_blocks.html

Comment: rescue block does not handle UNREACHABLE condition, unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here there is my solution based on https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/25532#issuecomment-428386816

Modify

/lib/python3.10/site-packages/winrm/protocol.py

```
class Protocol(object):
    def __init__(
            ...
            reconnection_retries=0,
            reconnection_backoff_factor=2.0
        ):
        ...
        
        self.transport = Transport(
            ...      
            reconnection_retries=reconnection_retries,
            reconnection_backoff_factor=reconnection_backoff_factor
        )
```

/lib/python3.10/site-packages/winrm/transport.py

```
class Transport(object):
    def __init__(
        ...
        reconnection_retries=0,
        reconnection_backoff_factor=2.0):
        
        ...
        self.reconnection_retries = reconnection_retries
        self.reconnection_backoff_factor = reconnection_backoff_factor
        ...
        
    def build_session(self):
        ...
        
        # Merge proxy environment variables
        settings = session.merge_environment_settings(url=self.endpoint,
                      proxies=proxies, stream=None, verify=None, cert=None)
        # ADD
        # Retry on connection errors, with a backoff factor
        retries = requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry.Retry(total=self.reconnection_retries,
                                                             connect=self.reconnection_retries,
                                                             status=self.reconnection_retries,
                                                             read=0,
                                                             backoff_factor=self.reconnection_backoff_factor,
                                                             status_forcelist=(413, 425, 429, 503))
        # ADD
        session.mount('http://', requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))
        session.mount('https://', requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))  
        ...
```

Now it is possible to control the retry when the node is unreachable

```
- name: Test
  hosts: mylocalwin
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    ansible_winrm_reconnection_backoff_factor: 2.0
    ansible_winrm_reconnection_retries: 4

  tasks:
    - name: Hello
      ansible.windows.win_powershell:
        script: | 
          Write-Host "hello"
```

I checked the solution with tcpdump and I can confirm then the TCP SYN groups are re-sent for `reconnection_retries` times.

Here there is a small recap about performaces

```
TYPE                ERROR DETECTION (sec)   NUM OF TCP SYN SENT
RETRY_0_BACKOFF_2   30                      5
RETRY_1_BACKOFF_2   60                      10
RETRY_2_BACKOFF_2   94                      15
RETRY_3_BACKOFF_2   133                     20
RETRY_4_BACKOFF_2   179                     25
RETRY_5_BACKOFF_2   240                     30
NO_RETRY_MECHANISM  30                      5
```

Comment: Adding my own answer as right just because I received no other alternatives

Comment: Is there a solution using ping or win_ping with retry mechanism?

Comment: I don't understand. I'm asking about a task during playbook execution. Not interested on win_ping

Comment: You've got unreachable error message meaning a communication problem